# Passing value types between block

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

From what I've understood it's possible to make an object available between blocks (and queues?) by using the __block modifier.

```
-(void)performRequest: (void (^)(NSArray* outcome))completion
 {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
                // do some request

            __block NSArray * result = [[NSArray alloc]init]; //Outcome of the request.

            completion(result);
        });
}
```

**Let's assume that the completion block will dispatch_async on the main thread**

I suppose it should be possible to do this with value types without the __block identifier. Im I right?

```
-(void)performRequest: (void (^)(int outcome))completion
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
            // do some request

        int result = 10; //Outcome of the request.

        completion(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: How is your example 1 and 2 similar? In the first one any change to `result` inside completion will reflect on `result`. In second one you are passing `10` directly to the block. `result` will not be changed at all irrespective of what you do in completion block.

Comment: You need to check http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `__block` in your first code snippet is completely pointless.

The entire purpose of `__block` is to make the value remain mutable when captured in another block. You're not capturing `result` anywhere.

Note that under MRR, `__block` has the side-effect of preventing the capturing block from retaining the value, making it an oft-used way to break a retain cycle. Under ARC, this isn't true. If you need to avoid a retain cycle then you need to use an `__unsafe_unretained` or `__weak` value. That said, again, none of this applies to your presented code snippet.

Comment: Ok. So without __block it would be immutable in other blocks? What If it was captured by another queue (let's say it's an instance variable)

Comment: @johan: `__block` only affects the variable. It doesn't change the underlying value. If you pass your `__block`-qualified `result` variable to another function, the `__block` is discarded. It's just like if you assign it to another variable.

Comment: @johan: So unless this explicit *variable* is captured by another queue, `__block` is meaningless.

Comment: @johan: Also, unless you actually need to mutate the variable, or if you're in MRR and you're trying to avoid retain cycles, then you don't want `__block` even when it is captured by another queue.